# How to target hidden div and image classes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

new to js and I am using an image filtering jquery library (filterme) and a cropping library (cropit).

I am trying to target a hidden div class created by the cropit library for usage with my image filtering library. How do I target the hidden div and image classes that can only be seen through the inspector?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery and wanted to find elements are are hidden, you can use the [`:not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:visible`](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selectors along with the types you are targeting :

```
var hiddenThings = $(':not(:visible)');
```

If you wanted to explicitly target certain types of elements, like `<div>` and `<img>` elements, you could adjust this accordingly :

```
 var hiddenDivsAndImages = $('div:not(:visible),img:not(:visible)');
```